# i have a list<Object []> return null result

Tags: spring, hibernate, collections

public List findPostByName(Long[] Poste, String Nom) throws ServiceException {
        List resultat= null;

```
    try {
        resultat =  this.entityManager.createNativeQuery
            (
            "SELECT "
            + "id, "
            + " non, "
            + " prenom, "
            + " direction, "
            + " emplacement "
            + "FROM intervention "
            + "WHERE Post= :Post"
            + "AND Nom= :Nom"
            )
            .setParameter("Post", Arrays.asList(Post))
            .setParameter("Nom", Nom)
            .getResultList();
        log.info("=============GETRESULTAT========>>>"+resultat);

    }catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return resultat ;
}
```

Comment: can paste the stack trace here

Comment: That's because you ignore the exception instead of fixing the problem. Don't catch Exception. Let it bubble, and fix the bug it signals. My guess is that your table doesn't have a column named `non`. Also, don't use a native query. Use a JPQL query. And aa post will never, ever be equal to a list of posts.

Comment: its not a answer thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

There must be some exception, you need to log the stacktrace and then fix the problem. Query.getResultList() will never give you null list. You can debug the problem by firing below query and then adding the parameters:

```
    "SELECT "
        + "id, "
        + " non, "
        + " prenom, "
        + " direction, "
        + " emplacement "
        + "FROM intervention "
```